# Neural network model does not converge

Tags: r, neural-networks

I am using function `neuralnet` in the package `neuralnet` to build the neural network, and I see the error:

`algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repetition(s) within the stepmax`

The neural network has 20 inputs and 1 output. The problem is, with the same data and same set of inputs, I ran linear regression or random forest without any problem. So what should I look to for debugging my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try with increasing the `rep` argument.
If it fails, try with increasing the  `stepmax` argument too.

One repetition of the training is called an epoch.
Usually, several epochs are needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Cloud Skywalker. I increased ``rep`` to 2, but it seems to me that the ``neuralnet`` function now runs very slow, it takes more than twice of duration when ``rep == 1``. Is it usual?

Answer (score 1):

The `rep` argument is basically how many times you train your neural network. [See the answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518511/neuralnet-in-r-what-are-the-difference-between-stepmax-and-rep-parameters) Therefore the higher the `rep`, the longer it will take.

You should increase the `stepmax` to give your model more chances to learn/converge. Or you can increase your `threshold` to allow an earlier stop for convergence. Alternatively, you can adjust your model, e.g. lower the number of your hidden layers and nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the stepmax value from the default 1e+05 to 1e+08 makes the algorithm take exponentially more time. E.g. 90s for `stepmax=1e+05` took 4h for `stepmax=1e+08`!

So preferably increase first the threshold from its default = 0.01 successively to 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc because this doesn't affect performance.